# Compare the values in the successive rows and display newly added or deleted items in a different columns

Tags: sql

I have a database with date and list of items. The problem this I do have an event date captured whenever an item is added or deleted. So what I am trying to do is comparing the items for a user 'A' on different days (successive rows); here the newly added or deleted items for user 'A' should be displayed in new columns 'Items added' and 'Items Removed'

```
   Date   |         Items List                              
-------------------------------------------------------------
24th July | Item A, Item B, Item C, Item D                                     
27th July | Item A, Item B, Item C, Item D, Item E, Item F   
28th July | Item A, Item D, Item E, Item F, Item G
```

Expected output for user 'A':

```
   Date   |         Items List                             |   Items Added      |  Items Removed 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24th July | Item A, Item B, Item C, Item D                 |                    |
27th July | Item A, Item B, Item C, Item D, Item E, Item F |    Item E, Item F  |    
28th July | Item A, Item D, Item E, Item F, Item G         |      Item G        |   Item B, Item C
```

I'd really appreciate if someone help me do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  This is also a very poor database format.  You should have a table with one row per item.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have it one row per item but I have used STRING_AGG to list all the items of one particular user; please see below:


`SELECT 
    *
FROM (
SELECT 
  id,
  date,
  STRING_AGG(items) AS itemslist,
  COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS count
FROM items_list,
GROUP BY 1,2 
order by 1,2
) b 
WHERE b.count > 1
ORDER BY b.date DESC`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have date for every row/every item; then the items list for a particular user in bigquery is updated for each date (recent date) whenever an app is added or deleted. Is there any better way I can do this?

Comment: . . You should ask a *new* question showing your original data and the results you want.  You can accept my answer in the meantime ;)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: This is not a great database design. I would suggest avoiding lists in columns, and establish a 1:N relationship between tables. As it is most queries will become unnecessarily expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a really bad data model, it is something of a fun question.  Because Postgres was one of the original tags, there is a Postgres version:

```
select date, items,
       string_agg( case when prev_date = prev_item_date then null else item end, ', ') as new_items,
       string_agg( case when next_date = next_item_date then null else item end, ', ') as removed_items
from (select t.*, item,
             lag(date) over (partition by item order by date) as prev_item_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by item order by date) as next_item_date
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
                   lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
            from t
           ) t cross join
           regexp_split_to_table(t.items, ', ') item
     ) ti
group by date, items;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d016283ae007787acbe92319b4db232) is a db<>fiddle.

In BigQuery, the logic is basically the same, just some nuances for unnesting the string:

```
select date, items,
       string_agg( case when prev_date = prev_item_date then null else item end, ', ') as new_items,
       string_agg( case when next_date = next_item_date then null else item end, ', ') as removed_items
from (select t.*, item,
             lag(date) over (partition by item order by date) as prev_item_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by item order by date) as next_item_date
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
                   lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
            from t
           ) t cross join
           unnest(regexp_extract_all(replace(t.items, ', ', ','), ',')) item
     ) ti
group by date, items;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response; the issue I'm facing here is with the line we are cross joining `unnest(regexp_extract_all(replace(t.items, ', ', ''), ',')) item`. It seems like big query is not supporting table valued functions

Comment: hence I am just getting ',' in 'item' column when I run

Comment: select date, items, string_agg( case when prev_date = prev_item_date then null else item end, ', ') as new_items,string_agg( case when next_date = next_item_date then null else item end, ',') as removed_items from (select t.*, item, lag(date) over (partition by item order by date) as prev_item_date, lead(date) over (partition by item order by date) as next_item_date from (select t.*, lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date from t) t cross join unnest(regexp_extract_all(replace(t.items, ', ', ''), ',')) item  ) ti

Comment: @AshaPondicherry . . . I have included a db<>fiddle (using Postgres) that shows that the logic works.